# How to change what an object is referring to within a function for all functions

Tags: python, object, reference

I'm implementing rehashing of dictionaries, so i have 2 hash tables, and i am trying to set the old one to refer to the new one.

i have something along the lines of:

```
def fart(hashTable):
    hashTableTwo = mkHashTable(100)
    hashTable = hashTableTwo
def main():
    hashTableOne = mkHashTable(50)
    fart(hashTableOne)
    print(hashTableOne.size)
```

mkHashTable(50) makes an object HashTable with 50 as its size.
This prints 50 and i want it to print 100.

What i have doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to make it work? I am not allowed to use global variables or objects

Answer (score 0):

assignments (=) in Python is name binding.

So `hashTable = hashTableTwo` in the fart function will not change the original hashTable, it just bind the variable name `hashTable` in the fart function to the `hashTableTwo` object.

check this post [Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither.](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

The workaround depends on the data structure/object type of hashTable. `dict` provides some methods to update its values.

```
def update_dict(bar):
    bar = {'This will not':" work"}


def update_dict2(bar):
    bar.clear()
    bar.update(This_will="work")


foo={'This object is':'mutable'}

update_dict(foo)

print foo

>>> {'This object is': 'mutable'}


update_dict2(foo)

print foo

>>> {'This_will': 'work'}
```